# Environment Setup egghead.io Tutorials?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, installation

hope things are going well.

I'm attempting to setup my development environment to be able to effectively follow the AngularJS tutorials on http://egghead.io/. I've followed the tutorial on http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial and have since then been playing around with the angular-seed skeleton. I have successfully set up the angular-seed skeleton and am able to fully run it.

When I attempt to create js files with functions, such as the one in video 2. I'm not able to properly bind it to html element on index.html. I believe the issue may be with how routing is implemented in the angular-seed. I have node.js installed and am able to start the web server from the scripts folder in the angular-seed.

I'm really excited to begin working with AngularJS after I had the opportunity to work with ASP.NET MVC 4.  I really like the information John provides in the tutorials on egghead.io, but I'm currently unable to fully emulate his instructions. It looks like he is JetBrains WebStorm, but I have no interest in purchasing it, if possible.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit 1:

For Example. In video 2 on the egghead.io tutorials. He creates a js file called main.js where he put a customer function and refers to it as an angular controller in index.html:

```
    function FirstCtrl($scope){
       $scope.data = {message: "Hello"};
    }
```

Wouldn't a controller need something to exent of:

```
    angualar.module('myApp',[]).controller('FirstCtrl', function(...){});
```

For angular to have it work as a controller on index.html? I'm able to add some of these functions to controllers.js of the angular-seed and make them work to some extent. Would it best to perhaps still use angular-seed and put the controllers/model/etc he displays some way into it's structure?

Comment: code example would be nice ^^

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using angular-seed and placing the controllers/services/etc he is creating into controller.js for the first few videos. I was able to successfully output the correct information he is displaying in the videos. By the end of video 5, my code in controllers.js looked something like this:

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('Data', function(){
    return {message:"I'm data from a service"}
})

myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function FirstCtrl($scope, Data){
    $scope.data = Data;
});

myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function SecondCtrl($scope, Data){
    $scope.data = Data;

    $scope.reversedMessage = function (message) {
        return message.split("").reverse().join("");
    }
});
```

At first I was using sublime text 2 and command line (node.js expressjs server), but recently I started using Visual Studio and created an empty website. I transferred all the folders/files of angular-seed into the website structure and I longer need to run node.js expressJS from the scripts\web-server.js. VS2013 has angularJS auto-complete features so it makes it easier.

I really like his tutorials and I'm glad I'm now able to successfully follow them to start learning angularJS.

Thanks!